# Switching to temporary buffer

Tags: buffers

This function makes a temporary buffer, inserting text stored in `msg`.  Hitting `q` will quit the temporary buffer.

My problem is that The cursor does not move to the temporary buffer as is done with `*Backtrace*`.

```
(defun help-show (bfname msg)
  "Display the output of MSG"

  (when (stringp msg)
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer bfname
      (pop-to-buffer bfname)
      (print msg))))
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your Emacs config, probably your `display-buffer-alist` config. Running `M-:` `(help-show "*gahh*" "test")` pops the temporary buffer and locates active point into it. Run Emacs with `emacs -Q" and try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the problem by taking out `pop-to-buffer` from inside `with-output-to-temp-buffer`.

```
(defun help-show (bfname msg)
  "Display the output of MSG"

  (when (stringp msg)
    (with-output-to-temp-buffer bfname
      (print msg))
    (pop-to-buffer bfname)))
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, thank you!